# HTML form drop-down filter now showing data through PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a HTML Form to display data from MYSQL TABLE fetched by PHP script in a drop down window.

My Problem is it displays the Value which i have defined as ALL in HTML form OPTION but it does not display the data thru PHP script. Please Help

My code is as follows:-

```
        <form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>


        <label>Design Category</label>
        <select name="dlocation">
        <option value="">All</option>

        <?php
            $connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root','password','dz');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM DEGSUBMIT GROUP BY dlocation ORDER BY dlocation";
            $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection );
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["dlocation"]."'".($row["dlocation"]==$_REQUEST["dlocation"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["dlocation"]."</option>";
            }

            ?>
        </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: You are not using mysql are you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: i am using mysql surely

Comment: Do you see the red box in th link above? Also you can read about SQL injection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: i ahev seen the red box.. but wats the mistake i am making ause i still am not getitng dtaa

Comment: What is the point of finding the problem when it's deprecated and dangerous code?